# String index out of Range: 2 No idea why this is appearing

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class example{

static String next(String base, String n){

    for(int i= n.length(); i>=0; i--){
        //i= n.length()-1;
        char digit= n.charAt(i);
        int pos= base.indexOf(digit);

        if(pos == base.length()-1){

            n= n.substring(0,i+1)
            + base.charAt(0);
        }//if end

        else{

            n= n.substring(0,i)
            + base.charAt(pos+1);

            break;
        }//else end

    }//for end

    return n;   

}//next end

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.print("Enter the Base: ");
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        String base= input.nextLine(); //base number
        System.out.print("Enter Starting Number: ");
        String n= input.nextLine(); // starting number
        //System.out.print("Enter the Last Number: ");
        //String m= input.nextLine(); //last number

        System.out.println(next(base,n));

}//main end
}//class end
```

When I enter base `0123456789` and the number "12" it should give me "13" since it's going one POS up of the base, but instead it give me this error if I add it in the for loop.

If I get rid of the for loop and the if statement it works fine.

Comment: You should learn to use your IDE debugger.  Stepping through the code you would have been able to find the problem yourself in 5 minutes.

Comment: The first dubious thing is that you're using `n.length()` (i.e. `2`) as boundary, instead of converting `n` to an integer (i.e. 12). For the rest, you should read the stack trace of the exception, and use your debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `n.length()-1` instead of `n.length()` like this:

```
   for(int i= n.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
```

Of course the index of n string start from `0` to `n.length()-1` not to `n.length()`.

Answer (score 5):

Java is a 0-indexed language, meaning the last index of an array or a string is `length-1`. So you should replace:

```
for(int i= n.length(); i>=0; i--)
```

by:

```
for(int i= n.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
```

Comment: i'm sorry i'm new to programming. It did work, but I don't understand. if n.length()-1 is used i would be "0" making the formula confusing.. how does this work?

Comment: @A.Nam yes that's right, `i` will be 0 on the last cycle, which is used as the first position in Java. What confuses you?

Comment: in the for loop.. if I put i= n.length()-1 i>=0; i--) since it's decreasing, is the first value of "I" 1 or 0

Comment: @A.Nam if `n = "12345"`, `n.charAt( n.length()-1 ) → '5'`, `n.charAt(1) → '2'` and `n.charAt(0) → '1'`. Remember that `i--` happens *at the end* of the body of the `for` loop not at the beginning

Comment: Oh okay. So the first value of I in my class would be 1, not 0